# Powerapps Filter records in browse gallery based on value in dropdown

Tags: powerapps

this seems simple, but just can't see it. My dropdown has a list of surnames.The dropdown is populated by a table called Surnames. When I select 'Jones', I want to show all tasks assigned to Jones in the browse gallery data.(table call Tasks) is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter like below for the items of your gallery: (Assume you have a table called Account.

```
Filter(Account, AccountId = Dropdown1.Selected.AccountId)
```

Note: If you are using a datasource like SQL which has good delegation capabilities. You would get a good performance from this. In contrast, excel wouldn't work well with it.